# TypeErrror: at Reflect.getMetaData Nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, circular-dependency

I have two Netsjs modules

1-User

2-Admin

The schema for both modules is same. But there's one difference, the **user has default role 0 and admin has default 1**. As Admin is also called a user, so I want to use a single mongodb collection(users collection) for both of them. Or I want to send both of them in the same collection after signup.

But In the process I'm getting the following error

> [Nest] 756  - 15/12/2022, 3:54:34 pm   ERROR [ExceptionHandler]
> TypeError:
> at Reflect.getMetadata (D:\Noum\Data\CYBRNODE\MAN STACK\Cybrnode-Blog-Backend\Cybr-Blog-Nest-Backend\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:354:23)
> at DependenciesScanner.isInjectable (D:\Noum\Data\CYBRNODE\MAN STACK\Cybrnode-Blog-Backend\Cybr-Blog-Nest-Backend\node_modules@nestjs\core\scanner.js:302:26)

**Things that I'm doing to achieve to goal**

**user.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => {
      AdminModule;
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: User.name,
        schema: userSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService, AdminService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**admin.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => {
      UserModule;
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AdminController],
  providers: [AdminService, UserService],
  exports: [AdminService],
})
export class AdminModule {}
```

**admin.service.ts As I want to use the User collection in mongodb, so here I'm injecting UserModel into AdminServcie**

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name) private readonly adminModel: Model<userDocument>,
  ) {}

}
```

**I know the logic might have so many counter questions I'll accept all the questions and consider them as well. But first I want to resolve this Reflect.getMetadata issue...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bug in:

```
forwardRef(() => {
    AdminModule;
}),
forwardRef(() => {
    UserModule;
}),
```

Just replace with:

```
forwardRef(() => {
    return AdminModule;
})
forwardRef(() => {
    return UserModule;
}),
```

UPDATED user module:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        forwardRef(() => {
            return AdminModule;
        }),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([
            {
                name: User.name,
                schema: UserSchema
            },
        ]),
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [UserService, AdminService],
    exports: [
        UserService,
            MongooseModule.forFeature([
            {
                name: User.name,
                schema: UserSchema
            },
        ]),
    ],
})
```

[Nest MongoDB](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection)

> If you also want to use the models in another module, add MongooseModule to the exports section of CatsModule and import CatsModule in the other module.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand this part `Also add to exports property of user module:

 MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: User.name,
        schema: userSchema,
      },
    ]`

Comment: Thanks bro!. Now the error is gone. I'm currently also reading the NestJs docs that you mentioned in your answer. I'm trying to understand what actually happening in the solution you provided